# Как конвертировать файл .bat в exe посредством Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Как написать конвертер файлов .bat в exe посредством Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант А.

1. Написать парсер, преобразующий bat-файлы в некоторое внутренне представление.
2. Написать компилятор из этого внутреннего представления в PE, который сгенерирует соответствующий машинный код и сформирует все необходимые PE-заголовки и секции.

Вариант Б.

1. Написать небольшую программку сохраняющую bat-файл, лежащий в собственной секции данных во временный файл и исполняющую его ShellExecute-ом.
2. Написать вспомогательную утилитку, которая засунет произвольный bat-файл в секцию данных программке из пункта 1.

Обе задачи весьма нетривиальны, хотя вариант Б, конечно, полегче. Надо ли?

Comment: Собственно и размышлял с сторону пути Б, но вот в чём проблема не знаю как создать временный файл и запихнуть в него код батника